# Auth Guard navigating to base url in case of invalid url

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `authguard` and want to navigate to `/notfound` url in case of invalid url. Here is my `authguard`:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
        const self = this;
        const userId= route.params.id;
        if(!userId){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return from(this.authservice.httpUnauthorizedGet("/api/Users/isUserValid/" + userId)).pipe(
                map((data) => {
                    const dataUpdated: any = data;
                    if (dataUpdated.allowed === false) {
                        self.router.navigate(['/notfound']);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return dataUpdated.allowed;
                }),
                catchError(() => {
                    self.router.navigate(['/notfound']);
                    return of(false);
                }),
              );
        }
    }
```

This is working but in case of invalid url (example: `/users/1234`), it first navigate to base url( `http://localhost:4200`) and then navigate to `http://localhost:4200/notfound`. 
When I am on `/notfound` and I click back, instead on being navigated to `/users/1234`, I get navigated to baseurl.

I think this is happening because of `return false`. This results in navigating to base url and then `router.navigate` navigates to `/notfound`.

Is there any way, I can simply be navigated to `/notfound` instead of going to base url?

Answer (score 1):

Rather then putting 404 navigation logic in `AuthenticationGuard.ts`, I let `app.routing.ts` handle it. Can you please check out the following code and apply it accordingly if it works for you. For your info the authService I am using is ADAL but that shouldn't be relevant.

**authentication.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      if (this.authService.isLogged) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
      }
  }

canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canActivate(childRoute, state);
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Route[] = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    { 
        path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ], 
        canActivateChild: [ AuthenticationGuard ], children: [
            { path: '', component: MyOwnComponent },
            { path: 'foo', component: FooComponent },
            { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
        ]
    }
]

export const AppRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

The line below is the route that handles 404.

```
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
```